# QGIS Raster images in reverse order after merging

Tags: qgis

I am trying to merge two raster images but the result turns out to be the one shown in the screenshot below. Does anybody know how to fix the problem?

[image: After merging]

This is before the merge, but it is what I hope to achieve after merging.
[image: Before merging]

These are the parameters that I am using.
[image]

I believe this to be a mismatch of the CRS between the raster. Therefore, I have used the Warp function to standardise both raster to be EPSG:3379 - GDM2000 / Pahang Grid, and merge them again. But this turns out to be the result, only one side is showing:
[image]

I have tried doing it again (Reprojection and merge), now only other side is showing:[image]

I am not sure where went wrong.

Comment: Can we see the parameters you used for merging? And maybe the general location of your study area?

Comment: Done, thanks. Sorry for not providing any details beforehand.

Comment: What you see is normal if you think that the map area is covering longitude area from -180 to +180 degrees. You probably want that the canvas would be from 0 to 360 degrees for preventing the clip at the dateline. Does this sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error shows up in your screenshots: the merge algorithm is not able to transform your EPSG:3379 - GDM2000 / Pahang Grid rasters to the project target CRS on the fly. There's a way to avoid it and solve your issue.

I tried to merge two raster (Raster1 & Raster2) with the same settings as yours and get the same error and unexpected merged raster.

If you Warp/reproject both rasters first to EPSG:4742 (Reprojected/Reprojected2 in my example below) and then only do the merge operation, it should work fine as illustrated below

Two random rasters provided in EPSG:3379
[image]

Merge result of two EPSG:4742  reprojected rasters:
[image]